# Is it possible to overlay files in a Git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

A Git repository `A` contains another repository as a submodule `B`.

Can I add a file within the `B` subtree but commit it only to `A` ?

The requirement calls for a file that is not included in `B` to be stored in the `B` subtree within `A`. The file should be ignored when committing `B` but included when committing `A`.

An extension of the idea would see two versions of the file, an original in `B` and a customised version in `A`.  If such a `B` was cloned on its own then that copy would see the original file but within the submodule you would get the customised version from `A`.

Is this possible at all ?

Comment: No. It's possible that `the file should be ignored when committing B but included when committing A`. But not possible to add `B` as a submodule at the same time. If `B` is added as a submodule first, then the files under `B` can't be addde or committed to `A`.